# Is it possible to make the 3D view in the UV Editing context 'opaque'?

Tags: uv, 3d-view

When I set 'viewport shading' to solid in the 3D view panel in the UV Editing context, occluded geometry is still visible in edit mode:

[image: UV Editing]

A similar view in the Default context:

[image]

Is there any way  to get the Default behaviour to occur in the UV Editing context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable *limit selection to visible* in the header of the 3D view:

[image]

Comment: Ah! Thanks so much, this was becoming pretty annoying.