# Why does perspective always have xray on?

Tags: 3d-view

When I toggle x-ray in Edit mode, only the orthographic views toggle. The perspective view constantly shows xray and it is super annoying. I see face handles (the square to select them) as well as edges and vertices through the faces just as if xray was on, but it's not.

How can I turn it off so that while in Edit Mode, and with Solid display mode selected, I don't see through things as if xray mode is on?
Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTutF.png)

Left: In Edit Mode
Right: In Object Mode
Basically I don't want to see the edges and face handles through the faces in front of them.

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot, so we get a better idea of what you mean

Comment: Are you talking about the 'Limit Selection to Visible' checkbox (just to the the right of the 'Face Select Mode' button?

Comment: I updated. I was mistaken about seeing faces blended through.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28443/599. Though I suspect the problem is actually this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1385/599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs due to your *Start Clipping* being to small, to fix that open up your **<kbd>N</kbd>Panel**, then go to the **View** section and change the *Start* clipping value to **0.100**

[image]

Or either it could be the **Limit Selection to visible** button next to the *Vertex/Edge/Face Select* properties, as mentioned by Mike Metcalf

[image]

Comment: It was the clipping plane starting too soon. The "Limit Selection to Visible" button is what I was referring to when talking about "xray". I thought that was what it is called because the Lynda.com training refers to it as the xray mode or something.